# How to fix 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' error when scraping Booking.com for hotel prices?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrap booking, in general everything is fine, or seems to be, but the price variable returns an error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.

If I remove the price variable the code works perfectly and returns: Gloria Palace San Agustín Thalasso & Hotel,San Agustín, "8,1".

On the other hand, what should I add in the code so that it analyses the results of all the pages and not only the first one?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

html_text = requests.get('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.es.html?ss=Gran+Canaria%2C+Espa%C3%B1a&ssne=Playa+del+Ingl%C3%A9s&ssne_untouched=Playa+del+Ingl%C3%A9s&efdco=1&label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIClgEaEaIAQGYAQq4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4AuTj66MGwAIB0gIkNWQ2OTg1OTgtZDZkOC00MTVkLWIwM2YtN2FkYWY2YTk4ZTMw2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&lang=es&sb=1&src_elem=sb&src=index&dest_id=754&dest_type=region&ac_position=0&ac_click_type=b&ac_langcode=es&ac_suggestion_list_length=5&search_selected=true&search_pageview_id=08c937b2a48a0147&ac_meta=GhAwOGM5MzdiMmE0OGEwMTQ3IAAoATICZXM6DGdyYW4gY2FuYXJpYUAASgBQAA%3D%3D&checkin=2023-10-16&checkout=2023-10-20&group_adults=3&no_rooms=1&group_children=1&age=17&sb_travel_purpose=leisure').text


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')


# find all the hotel elements in the HTML document
hotels = soup.findAll('div', {'data-testid': 'property-card'})

hotels_data = []
# loop over the hotel elements and extract the desired data
for hotel in hotels:
    # extract the hotel name
    name_element = hotel.find('div', {'data-testid': 'title'})
    name = name_element.text.strip()

    # extract the hotel location
    location_element = hotel.find('span', {'data-testid': 'address'})
    location = location_element.text.strip()

    # extract the hotel price
    price_element = hotel.find('span', {'data-testid': 'price-and-discounted-price'})
    price = price_element.text.strip()
    
    # extract the hotel rating
    rating_element = hotel.find('div', {'class': 'b5cd09854e d10a6220b4'})
    rating = rating_element.text.strip()
    
    # append hotes_data with info about hotel
    hotels_data.append({
        'name': name,
        'location': location,
        'price': price,
        'rating': rating
        


    })
    
hotels = pd.DataFrame(hotels_data)
hotels.head()

hotels.to_csv('hotels.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

could someone help me to solve the problem of the price variable and tell me how I can do the pagination?

Thanks

Comment: Check whether `find()` was successful before trying to get the text.